# Any code examples of SpnegoContextToken with Java client?

Tags: java, wcf, kerberos, spnego

I'm trying to write Java code to be run on Windows to consume a WCF webservice that's using SpnegoContextToken.  Does anyone have a good working example that they can share?  I am not even sure if the current Metro (2.1) supports SpnegoContextToken.  I am grateful for any advice.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should check http://spnego.sourceforge.net/protected_soap_service.html for further details.

Also interesting are

http://waffle.codeplex.com/

and

http://spnego.java.net/

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I'm familiar with those projects already.  What I'm specifically looking for is an example on how to use Java to consume WCF services using SpnegoContextToken.